# API paths for Many to Many relationship

Tags: api, asp.net-core, api-design

I have the following entities on an Api:

```
Organization > OrganizationId (PK), Name, ...

User > UserId (PK), Name, ...

OrganizationEnrolment > (OrganizationId, UserId) (PK), EnromentTypeId
```

So `OrganizationEnrolment` has the enrolments of users in organisations.

An user can only have one enrolment per Organization so the PK `(OrganizationId, UserId)`.

I have a few API endpoints like:

```
GET Organization = GET organizations/{organizationId}

Update Organization = PUT organizations/{organizationId}

Create User = POST users

Delete User = DELETE users/{userId}
```

The question is:

What should be the API urls to Create, Delete and Update an Organization Enrolment?

I am struggling with it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Organization Employees: `GET organizations/{organizationId}/employees`

Attach Employees to Organization: `PUT organizations/{organizationId}/employees`

Remove Employees from Organization without deleting Employees: `DELETE organizations/{organizationId}/employees`

Comment: and remove one emoloyee `DELETE organizations/{organizationId}/employees/{employeeId}`